# is there a way to inspect the shape of merged interface in typescript

Tags: typescript

Interface can be modified in multiple places, and when I have mouse hover over the variable of that interface type in VSCode, it only displays the name of the interface.

```
//part 1
interface A {
  a:string;
}

//part 2
interface A {
  b:string;
}

//if part 1 and part 2 are defined very far away
//how do I inspect the final shape of interface A
let k:A = {a:'a', b:'b'};
```

In VSCode, right click the type A and select "go to Type Definition" can list the 2 parts, but I'm wondering if there is a way to inspect the merged shape.

Comment: What do you mean by *Interface can be modified in multiple places*?

Comment: redefining the same interface with new properties will actually merge the new properties with existing properties.